# How to make HTML look readbale in Js file

Tags: html

This is the HTML I have been given

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div class="prd-items-detials">
        <ul>
            <li class="head">
                <form>
                    <label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">' + itemname + '</label>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="prd-items-qt">
                <div class="col"><span class="prd-sm-img">
              <img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="'+image+'"/>
              <span>
              </div>
              <div class="col"><i class="minus"></i>
              <i class="qt qt_'+id_attr_val+'">1</i>
              <i class="plus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Topping</a></div>
              <div style="display: none;" class="price" >'+price+'</div>
              <div class="col total total_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div></li></ul>
              </div>
              // add it right after here 
              </div>
```

So in order to match the HTML, I am building it all in one variable  as shown below

```
buildcart.append('<div  data-role="collapsible"><div class="prd-items-detials"><ul><li class="head"><form><label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">' + itemname + '</label></form></li><li class="prd-items-qt"><div class="col"><span class="prd-sm-img"><img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="'+image+'"/><span></div><div class="col"><i class="minus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i><i class="qt qt_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">1</i><i class="plus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i></div><div class="col"><a href="#" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'" class="btn btn-sm">Topping</a></div><div style="display: none;" class="price" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div><div class="col total total_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div></li></ul></div><div class="TestTopping-details"></div></div>');
```

As a result this looks messy and unreadable  , is there any way i can clearly specify each line of css in seperate line , so taht it looks readable

Comment: you mean html, not css? look into some templating language, like handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com)

Comment: No i mean , i need something this way buildcart.append('<div  data-role="collapsible">                                                              <div class="prd-items-detials">

Comment: Each line coming under new line .

Comment: You could add a `\\` to the end of each line.

Comment: How to? You simply can't really. This is a design flaw and the solution needs to be sought elsewhere.

Comment: read the handlebars homepage, i think, it's exactly what you need. with handlebars you can write your html template inside a script tag, nice and clean, and insert your dynamic values with ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write multiline variables in javascript, add a backslash to the end of each line;

```
var html = "<div>\
<p>This is a multiline variable</p>\
</div>";

buildcart.append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [join('')](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) for this:

```
buildcart.append([
    '<div  data-role="collapsible">',
    '<div class="prd-items-detials">',
    '<ul><li class="head">',
    '<form>',
    '<label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">'+itemname+'</label>',
    '</form>',
    '</li>',
    '<li class="prd-items-qt">',
    '<div class="col">',
    '<span class="prd-sm-img"><img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="'+image+'"/></span>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="col">',
    '<i class="minus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i>',
    '<i class="qt qt_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">1</i>',
    '<i class="plus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="col">',
    '<a href="#" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'" class="btn btn-sm">Topping</a>',
    '</div>',
    '<div style="display: none;" class="price" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div>',
    '<div class="col total total_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div>',
    '</li>',
    '</ul>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="TestTopping-details"></div>',
    '</div>'
].join(''));
```